# How to add custom styles for Aem proxy components?

Tags: css, content-management-system, aem, aem-6

I have created one component which extends core image component. So i add new features to it called as Title. I am not able to add styles for the title component. What is the approach to add the styles for proxy components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First method:
   Define the css class in the more generic client library used for your project and include it in your component.

/apps/project/clientlibs
include in the html

2. Second method:
   You can create custom client library folder under your proxy component and define your css class in that to pick styles.

/apps/project/imagecomponent/clientlibs

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to show quick code example of both solution ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Like in second point, Can we add cleintlibs for each component inside the our components folder. Is that works ?